# FTP through HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, ftp

I have a machine, which is the Host and has HAProxy installed in it and working. Then I have a Guest KVM virtual machine running inside the Host with an IP `192.168.122.152`. I installed an FTP server in the Guest machine with VSFTPD.

From the Host, if I try the command `$ ftp -p 192.168.122.152`, works perfectly and I can connect to the Guest FTP. I need to remark that this FTP is configured as passive, but both passive and active connections are working from the Host.

This is an extract of part of `/etc/vsftpd.conf` in the Guest:

```
# Passive mode
connect_from_port_20=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
listen_address=192.168.122.152
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_promiscuous=NO
port_enable=YES
port_promiscuous=NO
pasv_max_port=10000
pasv_min_port=10250
```

Now it's time to make it accessible from outside, so I configure `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` like this:

```
listen FTP_Default *:21
  server ftp01 192.168.122.152 check port 21 inter 10s rise 1 fall 2

listen FTP_Range *:10000-10250
  server ftp01 192.168.122.152 check port 21 inter 10s rise 1 fall 2
```

But if I try to connect from other machine in internet `$ ftp -p $PUBLICIP`, it only responds: `Connected to <PUBLICIP>`, but it doesn't ask for the login and password.

Something in the HAProxy config must be wrong, because it's the only point where it fails. By the way, I tried to adapt my configuration to [this one in this blog](http://www.taiter.com/techlog/2012/09/ftp-load-balanced-through-haproxy.html).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the solution. It seems I had to use a directive `pasv_address` with the IP of the system. I will post again the settings I've used to make it work.

Supposing our public IP is `217.130.100.62`, here we have an extract of `/etc/vsftpd.conf` in the Guest:

```
# Passive mode
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_address=217.130.100.62
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_promiscuous=NO
port_enable=YES
port_promiscuous=NO
pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=10250
```

And here, a simplified directive in `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` in the Host:

```
listen FTP :21,:10000-10250
    mode tcp
    server ftp01 192.168.122.152 check port 21
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplified directive in your haproxy config will result that all ports (21, 10000-10250) will always be redirected to port 21. 
This will give you the following error:

```
"425 Can't open data connection for transfer of..."
```

To fix this, if you do not define a port, the port where the request is received on will be redirected to the backend.

```
listen ftp-host01
   bind *:21
   bind *:10000-10099
    mode tcp
    server ftp-host01 192.168.1.1 check
```