# Dns multiple server forwarding

Tags: windows-server-2019, ubuntu-20.04

I have host name `ftp.example.com`

Can it be redirected by DNS to different servers
For example `ftp://ftp.example.com` to server 192.168.xx.1
`https://ftp.example.com` to server 192.168.xx.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by DNS, but this is possible with a proxy server. Here is a very basic example for HAproxy:

```
listen http :80
    mode http
    server http1 192.168.xx.1:80 check

listen FTP :21,:10000-10250
    mode tcp
    server ftp01 192.168.xx.2 check port 21
```

The FTP part is [explained in more detail here](https://serverfault.com/questions/441721/ftp-through-haproxy). HTTP proxy configuration is very common, you'll find many examples for it.

Comment: And  delete the ptr recored from dns?

Comment: Well, you need to have a DNS record that points to the machine that runs the proxy server.

Comment: Server ftp01 is the server host name?

Comment: It's just a name used internally by haproxy. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: i installed the server, i put the example in the setting in the defaults section in the haproxy.cfg file ?